# How do I tactfully bring up database shortcomings?

Tags: sql-server, security, best-practices

A little background:

I recently inherited responsibility for support and development of a database application after the original developers left. Looking through the application, the database appears to have several... issues.

- Weekly shrink and re-index plan
- Database account used for web application access has db_owner role
- No foreign keys
- All tables use GUID column as primary key
- Queries built in C# are not parameterized

How can I bring these issues up with management?

Normally, this should be no trouble, but I have a problem: I have less than six months of SQL experience, whereas the managers and former developers were working on this project for several years.

Comment: "*Queries built in C# are not parameterized*" - bring it up as a security risk (SQL injection).

Comment: This design sounds vaguely familiar, please tell me that you don't work at a financial institution.

Comment: Probably my bank!

Comment: While there are some DBA-related specifics, this sounds a lot more like [a politics question for workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/) than a technical one.

Comment: Explain, why these issues result in increased cost (or risk which is cost plus a probability). Nobody cares about issues that do not result in more cost or less revenue (rightfully so).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure you have a mountain of documentation, both of your current system's flaws, and how to fix them. It's no use just saying "everything sucks bad" unless you have a plan, and can show real benefits to the business of making the change.

Answer (score 10):

Here's the line I like to use - it preserves everyone's dignity and lets everyone escape without finger-pointing:

"Yes, that used to be a best practice, and..."

It’s almost easier to explain that line in terms of what it DOESN’T do.  It doesn’t dispute the speaker’s claim, because you don’t want to go down the rathole of arguing about whether or not the point was right at the time.  You could spend the entire day arguing about why USB has the word Universal as part of the name, but that’s beside the point.  You need to get to the right solution as fast as possible, and sometimes that just means ignoring something that’s wrong.

It doesn’t chastise the other guy for not keeping up with the latest tips and tricks.  It’s hard enough to just do our jobs, let alone keep up with blogs and training, and real life interferes.  It lets the other person save face.

It doesn’t divide you against the other guy.  I try to use the word “we” whenever I use this line, because I want to take the other guy along with me on the journey to fix this problem.

I've written more about it in [my Consulting Lines series.](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/02/consulting-lines-yes-that-used-be-best-practice-and/)

Comment: You're probably more experienced and better at dealing with this type of situation than almost anyone, but still I'm confused. Are you saying that in this situation you'd say that it used to be a best practice to shrink files weekly and give the app account the db_owner role? Maybe I'm taking you too literally.

Comment: +1, @Brent is saying "be diplomatic" since it accomplishes nothing to point the finger.

Comment: The weekly shrink and reindex sounds like a naive "solution" to a performance problem. The app with the db_owner role again, sounds like a "quick-fix" to satisfy impatient management... the same management you want to talk to about what was done wrong maybe? Think about that.

Comment: @James exactly, I'm saying let them believe it used to be a best practice. That lets them escape with dignity. There's no need to rub their face in what they did - as long as you can get the result you want an easier way, do it.

Answer (score 2):

### Facts

Seriously, it's all about facts.

> I have less than six months of SQL experience, whereas the managers and former developers were working on this project for several years

That means nothing to me.  I'd rather work with a 6-month DBA that has the thirst for knowledge and engineering approach to databases, then an "experienced" person that thinks they have it all figured out.

Document, document, and then document some more.  Be extremely specific.

#### Show examples/demos/repros illustrating your points

All of those items you listed can be demo'd quite easily.  Spend a little extra time and show in a test/isolated environment the way they are doing it now, and why that is a problem.  Be scientific.  Show the pitfalls, whether it's data purity or performance.  Then show *your* way, and using the same "test" show why your way prevents issues or maximizes good things.

Just because you say "it is bad to not use foreign keys" doesn't mean all that much.  So you heard somebody else say it once.  But... if you have a repro showing *why* it's bad and how to correct it, now you are bringing something to the table.  And by spelling it out, any reasonable person would have a hard time not agreeing, whether your have 6 months of experience under your belt, or whether you're an MCM.  Take a look at all of the great professionals in our line of work, and look at their blog posts.  They don't just say "this is this way because it is the best".  They almost always show with an example what they are talking about to really paint the picture.  That is most effective.  ***Use examples***.

We are lucky that we are in a profession where facts are quite attainable.  That doesn't mean be abrasive or unprofessional.  At the end of the day we are all human.  And at some point you will be wrong as well, so treat the situation and issues as you'd like your discrepancies to be treated.  That's the "soft" side of our jobs.

Answer (score -2):

Be sure that your manager or team leader understands your point and is supporting you when you bring this up.